# Recovering records for EntitySubscription from recycle bin

Tags: recycle-bin

We have written a apex code to delete the followers on Opportunities for which close date is older than 30 days.

Now I am trying to recover some of deleted records from EntitySubscription object, however I cannot find these records in EntitySubscription object. (I used workbench and selected the option to include deleted records, but still there are no results and also I used ALL ROWS option, still did not work)

I tested in sandbox by following an opportunity and unfollowed that Opportunity and then I cannot find that record in EntitySubscription object deleted records list.

1. Does EntitySubscription object does not support recovery of records from recycle bin
2. Is there any way to retrieve EntitySubscription deleted records.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is check the [EntitySubscription](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm) and you'll see that it doesn't support undelete. In other words, you can't recover these records. They're gone for good. You can use [getDeleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm) to find those records for replication to other systems, but you'd only get the record Id of those records.